# Every JS file throws error until it's opened and saved on Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I'm deploying a node app to Azure, using local git deployment. I have it working without issues in the staging environment (also on Azure) and I'm now setting up a production environment.

Every single file involved in the app throws an error - but as soon as I open that file in my FTP client and just save it, without making changes, the error for that particular file goes away - and the next file used throws an error.

So the steps I took are something like this:

Run deployment, refresh browser.

Get error like `Unexpected token ILLEGAL on server.js line 1`

Save `server.js` in FTP client, without making changes.

Restart app, refresh browser.

`server.js` now has no issues, but the first file it requires, express, gives an error  `cannot find module ./lib/express` on `node_modules/express/index.js:11` (`./lib/express` is definitely there)

Save `node_modules/express/index.js:11` in FTP client, without making changes.

Restart app, refresh browser.

Now, `node_modules/express/index.js` has no issues, but the first file it requires, `./lib/express` will then give an error: `cannot find module merge-descriptors` on `node_modules/lib/express.js:16`

I'll stop there, but in real life I continued and the behaviour is consistently ongoing - each file errors on the first thing it tries to require, until it's been saved in the FTP client.

To top it all off, I left the app unchanged for 20 minutes, came back, and I was back to the beginning - with an `Unexpected token ILLEGAL on server.js line 1` despite NO changes to my code. I tried saving each file and basically just repeated the steps above, getting the same results.

I'm completely stuck and have no idea what to do next short of saving every single file in the codebase. Any idea what could be going on here, or how I could move forwards with debugging the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a [Byte-Order-Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of your files.

There is a simple [gist by Domenic Denicola](https://gist.github.com/domenic/2954904) that shows how you can detect and remove this for all files in the current directory:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var wrench = require("wrench");

var BOM_CHAR_CODE = 65279;
var BOM = String.fromCharCode(BOM_CHAR_CODE);

var fileNames = wrench.readdirSyncRecursive(process.cwd()).filter(function (fileName) {
    return path.extname(fileName) === ".js";
});

fileNames.forEach(function (fileName) {
    fs.readFile(fileName, "utf8", function (err, fileContents) {
        if (err) { throw err; }

        if (fileContents.charCodeAt(0) !== BOM_CHAR_CODE) {
            fs.writeFile(fileName, BOM + fileContents, "utf8", function (err) {
                if (err) { throw err; }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Running that gives me "Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open". I could try limit the # of files it keeps open at a time, but it should just work - it's working in our other Azure environment, and we don't want to be having to run that script on every deploy, so I'm just going to open a support ticket with Azure. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After being in touch with Azure support, it turns out the issue was due to `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE` being set to 1, not 0. The feature isn't visible in the azure portal, and is "in development and is currently in private preview." The issue I came across is a known bug with `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE` and node apps.

We're still not sure how / why it got set to 1 in the first place, but it's fixed, so we don't care for now.

What a fun day!